# Como puedo buscar el valor medio de un elemento de un array? en Java

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

solo quiero saber como calculo el numero de en medio de un array, hasta ahora este es mi codigo, he conseguido el mayor y el menor, que logica tengo que usar para conseguir el medio usando el mismo sistema de for ?

````
    //busca el mayor
                    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
                        if (mayor < numeros[i]) {
                            mayor = numeros[i];
                        }
                        System.out.println(String.format("Posicion [%d] Elemento : %d", i, numeros[i]));
                    }
                    menor = mayor;
                    //busca el menor
                    for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
                        if (menor > numeros[i]) {
                            menor = numeros[i];
                        }
                    } ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Necesitarías ordenar el `array` ,puedes hacerlo mediante algún método de ordenamiento de tu preferencia o usando [`arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)),teniéndolo ordenado de forma ascendente, podemos determinar el `valor medio` por su nuevo `indice`

```
//ordenamos el array

int aux;
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < numeros.length; j++) {
    
    if (numeros[i] > numeros[j]) {
        aux = numeros[i];
        numeros[i] = numeros[j];
        numeros[j] = aux;
    
        }
      }
     }
        int menor=numeros[0];
        int mayor=numeros[numeros.length-1];
        int medio=numeros[(numeros.length-1)/2];
```

Comment: esta ha sido una manera muy ingeniosa de resolver el problema , te agrezco tu tiempo

Answer (score 1):

Espero que esto te pueda servir.

```
   int arreglo[] = {1,2,5,4,3,6 };
    // Comenzamos con el promedio, lo cual es la media
    int sumatoria = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < arreglo.length; x++) {
        sumatoria += arreglo[x];
    }
    double media = sumatoria / arreglo.length;

    Arrays.sort(arreglo);

    int mediana;
    int mitad = arreglo.length / 2;
    // Si la longitud es par, se deben promediar los del centro
    if (arreglo.length % 2 == 0) {
        mediana = (arreglo[mitad - 1] + arreglo[mitad]) / 2;
    } else {
        mediana = arreglo[mitad];
    }
    // Imprimir valores
    System.out.println("El arreglo es: ");
    for (int x = 0; x < arreglo.length; x++) {
        System.out.printf("%d ", arreglo[x]);
    }
    System.out.printf("\nLa media es %.2f y la mediana es %d", media, mediana);
    
    System.out.println(" El valor en la mitad del arreglo es: "+ arreglo[(arreglo.length-1)/2]);
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo , si me ha servido